# how to use css to display multiple posts in inline-block like google+

Tags: css

I'm fetching a several post from my database I will like the post to displaY inline-block. Well it display but is not perfect. I want it  to display. Like google+ posts.   The problem I detect is when the comment in the post in the left not equal to the one in the right that's y it not position well.  I av use several display method and its not working.

```
<style type="text/css">

/* this is the holder of the posts */
#container{
    width: 900px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.posts{
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px;
}

</style>
```

I want it to display like google+ posts which display inline even if the posts is longer than other.   Any suggestion will b  appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ separates its content into 3 columns. Nothing is set to display inline. To replicate this your markup would look something like this:

```html
<div id="container">
    <section>
        <article class="posts">Post 1</article>
        <article class="posts">Post 4</article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article class="posts">Post 2</article>
        <article class="posts">Post 5</article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <article class="posts">Post 3</article>
        <article class="posts">Post 6</article>
    </section>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    display: block;
}

#container section {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}

#container section .posts {
    display: block;
}
```

If you do want to do this in an inline fashion (similar to how Pinterest does it), you'll need to use JavaScript (or server-side code) to calculate the heights and widths of each `.posts` element and offset the element surrounding it appropriately (similar to [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/JamesDonnelly/Boxify.js) I made last month).

Comment: Thanks for your time and your plugin I will test it now

Comment: Using three section method how can I fill the section with posts coming from my db

Comment: That depends on how your posts are currently generated. You can simply  create a count variable which loops from 1 to 3, adding each new post into the required column with each loop.